# Making anchor (button) fit the same height as the text next to it

Tags: html, css

*Disclaimer: I have seen similar posts, but not one quite like mine, hence why I am posting now.*

At the moment I have the following:

```
<div class="textwidget">
<p style="width: 69%;">
Yo, I'll tell you what I want, what I really really want, 
So tell me what you want, what you really really want, 
I'll tell you what I want, what I really really want, 
So tell me what you want, what you really really want, 
I wanna, I wanna, I wanna, I wanna, I wanna really really really wanna zigazig ha. 
If you want my future forget my past, 
If you wanna get with me better make it fast, 
Now don't go wasting my precious time, 
Get your act together we could be just fine 
I'll tell you what I want, what I really really want, 
So tell me what you want, what you really really want, 
I wanna, I wanna, I wanna, I wanna, I wanna really really really wanna zigazig ha. 
</p>
<a class="button overlay-btn" href="http://www.google.com" >A link</a></div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.button, button, input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #ff6600;
  font-family: "futura-pt";
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
.overlay-btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

**I essentially want/need the button height to extend all the way down to the same bottom as the last line of the text.**

Is there a reasonable way to achieve this? As always the simpler the better.
I would really appreciate the help, since as a CSS beginner, I've been trying all day with no success.

Comment: Why won't you just include your anchor in the same <p>?

Comment: @RoboRobok just did, but didn't really change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's `display: table` solution - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wbkL9ow/)

```
.button, button, input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #ff6600;
  font-family: "futura-pt";
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
.textwidget {
  display: table;
}
.textwidget p {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 70%;
}
.overlay-btn {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
}
```

And you don't need this `style="width: 69%;"` in HTML. Also you can use `vertical-align: middle` with `display: table-cell`, so try to combine it with `text-align: center`.

**UPD:** http://jsfiddle.net/4wbkL9ow/1/ - it looks pretty nice I think.